# Replacing fragments in ViewPager which uses FragmentStatePagerAdaptor

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have two tabs in one of my activities. The tabs are populated based on two lists in the activity. If the list is empty, I put a static fragment; else I load a ListFragment.

```
    @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:                      
                    if (list1 == null || list1.length() == 0) {
                        frag1 = EmptyFragment.newInstance();
                        return frag1;
                    } else {
                        frag1 = MyListFragment.newInstance(list1.toString());
                        return frag1;
                    }
                case 1:

                   if (list2 == null || list2.length() == 0) {
                        frag2 = EmptyFragment.newInstance();
                        return frag2;
                    } else {
                        frag2 = MyListFragment.newInstance(list2.toString());
                        return frag2;
                    }
                default:

                    return EmptyFragment.newInstance();
            }
}
```

I have implemented SwipeRefreshLayout on both the fragmants which calls a function in the parent activity to reload the data and replace the fragments.

Once data is loaded, I call notifyDataSetChanged() and in adaptor class I have

```
@Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

The problem is that once data is loaded, the old fragment is not replaced. Now there are two lists stacked on top of each other. One stays static and the other scrolls.
Tried calling

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(frag1).commit();
```

But that gives

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding/replacing the fragment? Try to replace like this:

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).apply()
```